# Foot splay whilst running

Tags: running, physiology, running-form, foot

[image]

Hi all, I’ve noticed that I have foot splay just on the right hand side whilst running. Is this a problem or just a natural quirk?

Anyone else experience this?

Thanks all.

Comment: It could also just be how your body aligns. My feet splay out naturally even when on ground.

Comment: @Markoid Are you talking about foot splay, as in the width of your foot, or foot splay, as in the image in your question the runners right foot is very clearly turned out to the side and not in line with his upper leg?

Comment: @JohnP if you mean your feet point outwards when you're standing, that's generally a sign of poor hip alignment or a mobility / strength issue somewhere along the chain. Obviously the degree of turn out matters, if it looks like you're doing that Charlie Chaplin walk, then that might hint at a future shoulder / hip / knee / ankle issue

Comment: @DarkHippo - Or, in some cases (such as mine), it's just how my bones formed. :)

Comment: @Dark Hippo - the latter...

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the ideal; your feet should splay to absorb impact as they strike the ground (ideally with a mid-foot strike)

http://www.barefootbeginner.com/2012/08/14/how-will-my-feet-change-when-i-become-a-barefoot-runner/

Folk who run in typical running shoes usually don't benefit from this foot splay, as their shoes keep their feet squeezed together.  However, there are programs and products out there to help bring back this natural foot movement:  https://www.nwfootankle.com/

Comment: Thanks for replying. I run in a wide range of shoes, most with a large toe-box, I splay in all shoes, which tells me that's it's not the shoes. Also, it's just one side. I've also noticed other runners doing it, and it does look inefficient. I can't tell from this picture of my hip is dropping. I'll try and get video from behind whilst I run, to see if it is related to my hips...

Comment: The original question is about foot splay, as in foot turn out. This article is about foot splay, how the width of the foot increases as you move to a more barefoot shoe and your foot strength increases